# Read from large array

Tags: php, arrays

I want to ask how can I read from my associative array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [imie;nazwisko;telefon] => 3;email@gmail.com;123456789
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [imie;nazwisko;telefon] => 6;email@gmail.com;123456789
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [imie;nazwisko;telefon] => 7;email@gmail.com;123456789
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [imie;nazwisko;telefon] => 16;email@gmail.com;123456789
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [imie;nazwisko;telefon] => 17;email@gmail.com;123456789
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [imie;nazwisko;telefon] => 19;email@gmail.com;123456789
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [imie;nazwisko;telefon] => 32;email@gmail.com;123456789
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [imie;nazwisko;telefon] => 39;email@gmail.com;123456789
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [imie;nazwisko;telefon] => 50;email@gmail.com;123456789
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [imie;nazwisko;telefon] => 52;email@gmail.com;123456789
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [imie;nazwisko;telefon] => 54;email@gmail.com;123456789
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [imie;nazwisko;telefon] => 720;email@gmail.com;123456789
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [imie;nazwisko;telefon] => 54;email@gmail.com;123456789
        )

)
```

I create this array with this code:

```
$csv = array_map("str_getcsv", file($path,FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES));
$keys = array_shift($csv);
foreach ($csv as $i=>$row) {
$csv[$i] = array_combine($keys, $row);
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($csv);
echo '</pre>';
```

How can I loop through all items and then **get from each item**:  imie,nazwisko and telefon?

Comment: You had some *real* email addresses and telephone numbers here. I've submitted an order to remove them from the revision history, but they've been scraped on [other sites](http://php.wekeepcoding.com/article/12143439/PHP+Read+from+quite+big+array). You probably want to contact these people and make sure they know that their information has been leaked, so they can take appropriate steps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a few loops and the `explode` function:

```
foreach($array as $arrIdx => $subArr){
   foreach($subArr as $keys => $values) {
         $key = explode(";", $keys);
         $value = explode(";", $values);

         for($i=0; $i <= 2; $i++){
            echo $key[$i]." : ".$value[$i];
         }
   }
}
```

Comment: That's great! Is there any possibility to check the number of columns instead of using static value? `for($i=0; $i <= 2; $i++){`

Comment: @forexknight use `$i < count($key)`

Comment: @forexknight Yes sure, change loop to `for($i=0; $i <= count($value)-1; $i++){ }`

Answer (score 0):

I would change the code of yours for this one:

```
$csv = array_map("str_getcsv", file($path,FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES));
$keys = explode(";", array_shift($csv));
foreach ($csv as $i=>$row) {
    $csv[$i] = array();
    foreach (explode(";", $row) as $j => $element) {
         $csv[$i][$keys[$j]] = $element;
    }
}
```

This way you obtain the correct associative array.